# Bitcoin cli asks to use estimatesmartfee with new syntax that is not described in docs

Tags: transaction-fees, fee-estimation

In previous versions of bitcoin-cli I've successfully used `estimatesmartfee 2` syntax. But now cli answers `{'errors': ['Insufficient data or no feerate found'], 'blocks': 0}`. How should I estimate fee now?

Comment: How long has bitcoind been running?

Comment: About 10 minutes

Comment: I use bitcoind v 0.16

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`estimatesmartfee` requires that bitcoind have been running long enough to gather data about the current fee rates on the network. This can take some time. Try running it again after a few hours, or a day or so, once it has collected data.